# Firebase Simple Login not playing nice with Heroku

Tags: heroku, oauth, firebase

I'm messing around with Firechat and setting up a simple test page using Heroku. I've attempted to set up Firebase Simple Login with Github. It works just fine when running on my local machine, however when running from the Heroku page I get an unrecognized origin error EVEN THOUGH I have added my Heroku domain to my list of authorized domains in Forge.

I've even tried copying the domain referenced directly out of the exception message and still no dice.

Is there something special I need to do with Heroku? Right now I'm using the Heroku assigned domain of the form http://thing-stuff-1234.herokuapp.com/

Comment: [Engineer @ Firebase] Ping me directly at support@firebase.com and I'd be happy to investigate your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Oops! I forgot to update this, problem was me. I was referencing the wrong FB in another block of code. (facepalm)